# HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.(For basic Authentication)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to enable "Basic" Authentication to my service. Disabled anonymous and windows Auth. And enabled "basicAuthentication" in applicationhost.config, but im not able access the service. Getting below error.

HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

I am using IIS Express 10. Here is my applicationhost.config

```
<authentication>

                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" userName="" />

                <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />

                <clientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false" />

                <digestAuthentication enabled="false" />

                <iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication enabled="false">
                </iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication>

                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false">
                    <providers>
                        <add value="Negotiate" />
                        <add value="NTLM" />
                    </providers>
                </windowsAuthentication>

            </authentication>
```

And here is my Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
  </system.web>

  <!--Enable directory browsing in the Server-->
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>



  <system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpTransportSecurity">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>



    <services>
      <service name="MyWCFServices.DemoREST" behaviorConfiguration="DemoREST">

        <!--Define base https base address-->
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://localhost:44300/HelloWorldService.svc/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <!--webHttpBinding allows exposing service methods in a RESTful manner-->
        <endpoint name="rest" address="" binding="webHttpBinding" 
             contract="MyWCFServices.IDemoREST" bindingConfiguration="webHttpTransportSecurity" 
                  behaviorConfiguration="DemoREST"/> 
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>      
        <behavior name="DemoREST">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to
         false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true. 
         Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>

          <!--Using custom username and Password-->
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyWCFServices.CustomUserNameValidator, HelloWorldService" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceAuthenticationManager authenticationSchemes="Basic"/>
        </behavior>

      </serviceBehaviors>

      <!--Required default endpoint behavior when using webHttpBinding-->
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="DemoREST">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And Custom validator class:

```
namespace MyWCFServices
{
    class CustomUserNameValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        // This method validates users. It allows in two users, user1 and user2
        // This code is for illustration purposes only and
        // must not be used in a production environment because it is not secure.
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {

            if (null == userName || null == password)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("You must provide both the username and password to access this service");
            }

            if (!(userName == "user1" && password == "test") && !(userName == "user2" && password == "test"))
            {
                // This throws an informative fault to the client.
                throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
                // When you do not want to throw an informative fault to the client,
                // throw the following exception.
                // throw new SecurityTokenException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Please guide me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: Can you try steps from this KB http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942043/

Comment: @Pranav, thanks for the update. But i have already tried the above one. I dont want windows Auth, I want basic auth to be enabled. And im using windows 10 + IIS Express

Comment: With `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` in your application, and ‘Anonymous access’ disabled and only ‘Integrated Windows Authentication’ in IIS, you will see the following results:
`System.Environment.UserName: ASPNET (user account used to run ASP.NET service)
Page.User.Identity.Name: Domain\ Windows Account Name 
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name: Computer Name\ASPNET`